# Excel Solver does not load and excel hangs

Tags: excel, vba, solver, freeze

I use solver.xlam quite a bit, and today I tried to open Excel, and it did not want to start, it was loading 'solver.xlam'and got stuck on 0%.

killed off all excel processes, then ran excel again and it suggested to deactivate solver. Clicked yes, and then all my vba code kept crashing at seemingly inocuous code, e.g. `cells(1,1).font.bold=true` would completely hang excel, requiring akill, and a restart.

eventually, after starting up and fidling some times, i switched the wifi off, and presto solver loaded, and my code was working fine. Currently in switzerland, (normal location Uk) I tried with wifi+vpn, and again solver loaded noproblem, and code ok.

So my question: how does the solver after being disabled as described above still break the vba code in other, unrelated workbooks (not calling solver...)

Comment: Uninstalling the solver and reinstalling is the usual way to get round any issues like this, as you describe.

Comment: hi,I could not reinstall, only disable, and that still left me unable to run basic formstting code....  (IT locked down the solver.xlam containing folder...). Only no internet, or wifi+vpn allowed excel to function normally

Comment: Not sure what you are saying, as the solver is an add-in that can be un and re - installed.

Comment: I mend that I could uninstall the solver within excel (as in stop excel loading solver.xlam), but i could not remove the file from the file system, and replace it with a new version

Answer (score 0):

had same issue, excel was not starting, it was hanging or freezing at solver.xlam, the above post give me a clue at what change in my pc since yesterday that was working fine.
Turnout that I had change my IP address to manual and assign an static IP because I needed to diagnose a PLC, nevertheless I had my laptop in the docking station and the network adapter was seeing an unidentified network, so I just switch it to automatic and try it and it worked.